# Please cancel the migration of “All pairs shortest path in undirected and unweighted graphs”

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

Question: [All pairs shortest path in undirected and unweighted graphs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/all-pairs-shortest-path-in-undirected-and-unweighted-graphs)

As discussed in [another thread](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/why-was-all-pairs-shortest-path-in-undirected-and-unweighted-graphs-closed-and), the question linked above had been migrated to math.stackexchange.com and the decision of migration was decided to be incorrect.  However, although the question on cstheory.stackexchange.com has been unlocked and reopened, the above link still redirects to math.stackexchange.com.  This is very confusing and kills the purpose of unlocking and reopening.  Please cancel the migration.

I had already asked this in a comment on [this post](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/why-was-all-pairs-shortest-path-in-undirected-and-unweighted-graphs-closed-and/1276#1276), but received no reply.

Comment: Is this even something the moderators have the power to undo?

Comment: @Lev: I do not know, but if it is impossible to cancel the migration, then I cannot see the point of reopening the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get your alert. (don't know why).

Yes, we can clear the migration history.

I kept it because Ryan's answer is there, I will post a link to Ryan's answer and clear the migration history.

Comment: Thanks! -------